# Windows are going black when mini/maximizing

Tags: drivers, nvidia, windows, 14.04

I´ve got 14.04 running perfectly on my desktop. There is however one slightly frustrating thing, which is that sometimes when I minimize a window, and then maximize it again the window is completely black.

Is there anyway to fix this? I have an Nvidia GTX 780 with the latest NVidia drivers.

I hope somebody could help me resolve this issue. I´ve been having it since 12.10.

Comment: Have you by any chance been playing around with the ['animations' section in the Unity Tweak Tool](http://i.stack.imgur.com/N38xu.png)?  Or the [minimize single window applications option in CCSM](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4nJkx.png)?  I've found the minimize-zoom and unminimize-none option to give me fewer black screens.

Comment: A workaround that always works on my machine is to drag the black window to the titlebar (maximizing it) and then resizing it (unmaximizing it). The window content then always reappears.

Answer (score 1):

This is a well known bug. Currently is no fix for it.

You can avoid it by turning off Animations, in ccsm (CompizConfig Settings Manager). 
Or reducing the amount of memory used by your video card.

More information can be found on the bug report page.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1072206

Answer (score 0):

My "black screen" problem solved by to turn off the "Window spread" option in Unity Tweak Tool (in the window manager tab).

Answer (score 0):

I was having these same issues with windows being black when I restored them from being minimized. This fixed it for me:

Unity Tweak Tool → General (Window Manager) → Turn Window Animations Off

My System:

```
Ubuntu 14.04 LTS x64
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 560 Ti 448 Cores
using NVIDIA binary driver - version 331.113 from nvidia-331(proprietary, tested)
```

Answer (score -1):

SOLVED! Playing with options at General Tab of Unity Tweak Tool, Broden Destop, Hardward Acceleration, Texture Quality ... Solved!

I've got the same problem. Black maximized windows. While restored I can see the icons. But when goes to maximized turn to black. The same occurs when system windows opens and they are fixed size windows (can't change its size). Ubuntu 14.04 and I'm using the last updated Nvidia driver ver. 304.117.

Comment: Can you please elaborate

Comment: Can you please tell us which options you changed, so that there is a chance that we can solve it as well?